# Which one is important: training or testing accuracy?

Tags: cross-validation, accuracy, model-evaluation

I split my data into 80% training and 20% testing data set. Using the 80% split and 10 cross-validations, I build the model and get the training accuracy. Then I test my model on the 20% split and get the testing accuracy.

**The question is:** which is important training or testing accuracy?
If I used 10 different machine learning algorithms on the same split, which accuracy will guide me for the best algorithm, training or testing accuracy?

---

I searched on CV, but the following similar questions are unanswered:

[Which model is better based on test and training accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303875/which-model-is-better-based-on-test-and-training-accuracy)

[Should I use training or testing AUC for selecting best classifier?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237610/should-i-use-training-or-testing-auc-for-selecting-best-classifier)

[Should using training datasets or testing datasets for evaluating the performance of the models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331605/should-using-training-datasets-or-testing-datasets-for-evaluating-the-performanc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The testing data in your cross-validation mimics the situation of "true" testing data. So if the performance of your model on new, not-before-seen data is important, then you should go by its performance on the CV testing data. (I have a hard time picturing a situation where training data performance is more important.)