# How am I supposed to choose model, based on the best validation set accuracy or last epoch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I trained the **VGG Network** on **cifar10**. Use my customized **noise label dataset** and clean dataset, then divide them into **train, validation and test sets**. In clean dataset everything went well, high performance on training and testing, but in the noise label dataset (60% wrong label), I'm confused which one should I choose, **the best validation accuracy** or **the last epoch**.

Here is the Result:

| Clean Data | Epoch | Train Acc | Validation Acc | Test Acc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Last Epoch | 120(final) | 99.83% | 93.01% | 92.63% |
| Best Validation Acc | 117 | 99.87% | 93.12% | 92.71% |

| Noise Label Data | Epoch | Train Acc | Validation Acc | Test Acc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Last Epoch | 120(final) | 44.66% | 44.36% | 43.06% |
| Best Validation Acc | 40 | 36.50% | 78.72% | 78.12% |

Here is the training step picture Link in Noise Label: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUDXt.png

[image]

After training more Epoch, my model is seemed to learn more about wrong label information, but if we use the validation accuracy this kind of trick to train model, I can get more higher performance.
Is it still reasonable to use the best validation accuracy to choose model in this case?
Even though the training accuracy is low.
By the way, I stopped Epoch in 120 due to the loss not increase anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which one is important: training or testing accuracy?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333124/which-one-is-important-training-or-testing-accuracy)

Comment: Thanks!!!! I realized that testing accuracy is the most important. Thank you:)